# how to set the "location / " of nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server and the wordpress is a sub dictionary in /home/wwwroot/.
the default domain page  is /home/wwwroot/index.html .
How can change the default domain page to /home/wwwroot/wordpress when access to www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `root /home/wwwroot/wordpress;` in the server block.

```
Server {
    root /home/wwwroot/wordpress;
    ...
    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```